# Use jQuery :has() and :contains() selectors together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list item element that contains a label element. I want to select the list item element with the `:has()` selector. Inside the label element there is text I want to match with `:contains()`. Is it possible to do both of these things with a single line of jQuery? If not, what is an elegant way to select the li element based on the contents of its child label element?

```
<li>
    <!-- I want to select this one -->
    <label>Label 1</label>
    <!-- more follows -->
</li>
```

Comment: `$("li:has(label):contains('Label 1'))`? My understanding is you want to select the `li` that both has a `label` and contains the text `Label 1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want either:

```
$("li:has(label):contains('Label 1')")
```

This will select any `<li>` that both has a `<label>` and contains the text `Label 1` anywhere inside of it.

```
$("li:has(label:contains('Label 1'))")
```

This will select any `<li>` that has a `<label>` and that label in particular contains the text `Label 1`. (The first selector will match if "`Label 1`" is *anywhere* inside the `<li>`.)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$("li:has('label'):contains('Label 1')")
```

Comment: Close! But this matches the label, not its parent li.